# working code in Ubuntu terminal, doesn't work in Windows Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, parsing, ubuntu

I'm trying to parse day format like `"dd/mm/yyyy"` with `useDelimiter` but faced a strange problem. I used the code below, which works well on Ubuntu terminal.

```
Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
k.useDelimiter("/|\n");
String day,month,year;
day = k.next(); month = k.next(); year = next();
System.out.println(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
int d = Integer.parseInt(day);
int m = Integer.parseInt(month);
int y = Integer.parseInt(year);
```

But on Windows when I copy this code to Eclipse, it gives an error at :

```
int y = Integer.parseInt(year);
```

I've found what causes this. When i print "year", it prints 2014 but there is some whitespace at the end of `2014` so the integer isn't parsed correctly. I solved this by changing the code in Eclipse to:

```
year = next().trim();
```

BUT :

My question is, how can it be possible that the same code works on Ubuntu but not on Windows platform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding \r to the delimiters.
In Ubuntu new line is only \n while in Microsoft new line is '\r\n'

Comment: Not just Ubuntu--nearly all Unix systems use `\n` (linefeed) while Windows uses `\r\n` (carriage return, line feed).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a line.seperator. System.getProperty("line.separator") will retrieve a correct line separator that is used by your OS.

```
public class Tester {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    k.useDelimiter("/|"+newLine);
    String day,month,year;

    day = k.next(); 
    month = k.next(); 
    year = k.next();
    System.out.println(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);


 }
}
```

Comment: This is more flexiable solution, thanks for your advice